# Find Joint Probability Density Function

Tags: probability

Question:
Random variable $x$ is described by a PDF which is a constant between $x_0 = 0$ and $x_0 = 1$ and which is zero otherwise. $K$ independent successive experimental values of this random variable are labeled $d_1, d_2, \dots , d_K$. Define the random variables
$$
r = \text{second largest of} \: d_1, d_2, \dots , d_K \\
s = \text{second smallest of} \: d_1, d_2, \dots , d_K
$$
and determine the joint probability density function $f_{r, s}(r_0, s_0)$ for all values of $r_0$ and $s_0$.

Could anyone give me some direction? I try to find joint CDF but it fails.

Update my method:

Sort $\{d_i\}$ in decreasing order and relabel them. Then we have
$$
r=d_2 \:\: \text{and} \:\: s=d_{k-1}
$$
CDF 
$$
\begin{align}
F_{r, s}(r_0, s_0) &= P(r \leq r_0, s \leq s_0) \\
&=P(d_2, d_3, \dots d_k \leq r_0, d_{k-1}, d_k \leq s_0) \\
&=[\prod_{i=2}^{k-2}P(d_i \leq r_0)] \times P(d_{k-1} \leq r_0, d_{k-1} \leq s_0) \times P(d_k \leq r_0, d_k \leq s_0) \\
&= s_{0}^2r_{0}^{k-3}, \:\: \text{if} \:\: 0 < s < r <1
\end{align}
$$
Thus
$$
\begin{align}
f_{r,s}(r_0, s_0) &= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r_0 \partial s_0} F_{r, s}(r_0, s_0) \\
&= 2s_0(k-3)r_0^{k-4}, \:\: \text{if} \:\: 0 < s < r < 1 \\
&= 0, \:\: \text{otherwise}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_the_uniform_distribution

Comment: Search on m.s.e. under "order statistics" and you'll find various things.  Maybe even a solution to this same question. $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks! I think that order statistics can solve the problem! But I'm wondering whether my method is correct. I have updated my method above!

Comment: when you sort and relabel them, they become order statistics - no longer independent and they no longer have an identical distribution.

Comment: @BGM Do you mean that each d_i is no longer independent? If I don't sort and relabel them, there are still k-1 random random variables smaller than r_0 and 2 variables smaller than s_0.

Comment: yes but those $k - 1$ random variables are not specific, and hence you will need to use the multinomial coefficient to count how many ways to split the random sample.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand your meaning. I think I need to take a look at the proof of order statistics .